# Calling RESTful web service using a GET in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am struggling to send a GET request to my web service.

I have a web service set up that has values assigned to x and y values, where x represents a value A-E and y represents a value 1-5. Let's say that, the values are assigned to C1.

So if I point to the URL: x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/x/c/y/1 then I would get back a response of 'Success' and if x and y represent other values then I have messages for failure and so on for invalid data types.

I cannot seem to get it to work!

The web service contains the following logic:

```
log.info 'queryContext = ' + queryContext
def x = queryContext.get('x',"value")
def y = queryContext.get('y',"value")
def yN = y.toInteger()
log.info 'x = ' + x
log.info 'y = ' + y

if (x == 'C' ||  x == 'c' &amp;&amp; y == '4') return("Hit")
if (yN == 0 || yN > 5) return("Error1")
def checkX = ['A','a','B','b','C','c','D','d','E','e'].containsAll(x)
if (checkX == false){return("Error2")}</con:dispatchPath><con:dispatchXPath/><con:parameterDispatcherRuleContainer/><con:routeScript/><con:response name="Hit" id="13e72027-3b34-4771-931a-578bd023d584" httpResponseStatus="200" mediaType="application/json"><con:settings/><con:responseContent>{
    "Result":"HIT"
```

HTML/JavaScript code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                var obj = { x: $("#xcoord").val(), y: $("#ycoord").val()};
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/",
                    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script> 
<title>Battleships</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
X Coordinate:<br>
<input type="text" id="xcoord"><br>
Y Coordinate:<br>
<input type="text" id="ycoord"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try hitting with a hardcoded url from the javascript function in your html page? Something like `url: "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/x/c/y/1"` in `$.ajax()` call of `$(document).ready()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question states:

> So if I point to the URL: x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/x/c/y/1 then I would get back a response of 'Success'

Therefore you need to send the values in the URL. However your current jQuery code is sending them in the querystring, as you specify the `data` property of `$.ajax`, ie.

```
x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/?x=c&y=1
```

To fix this, set the URL of the AJAX request like this:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "http://x.x.x.x:xxxx/app/x/" + $("#xcoord").val() + '/y/' + $("#ycoord").val(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you. Just a note to anybody reading this, it will return Object Object in the alert so you have to stringify it first

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The `[Object object]` issue is because the `alert()` calls `toString()` on any value it gets. It's for that reason it's best not to use it and use either `console.log()` or `console.dir()` instead

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my vague question earlier... I should have done some research first and was being lazy!

Comment: That's ok. I thought I recognised this question as one I'd seen before :) Apologies if my comment on the previous question came across as rude. This one is much clearer and easier to understand.